# Why does x86 ldmxcsr/stmxcsr take a memory operand?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, sse

In x86, there is no way to directly [set](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ldmxcsr) or [store](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/stmxcsr) the MXCSR register from a general-purpose register. Forcibly encoding a register operand leads to #UD. This seems rather inefficient when the main use of the register is testing for floating-point exceptions or changing the floating-point environment, neither of which need bouncing through memory. The only obvious and realistic benefit of a memory operand is loading the register with a constant value without needing an extra register. But allowing a register operand doesn't at all complicate the encoding, so why not allow both? As a comparison, AArch64 manipulates its analogous FPCR (floating-point control register) with `msr fpcr, x0`, reading from a general-purpose register.

With AVX, Intel added VEX-encoded versions of the two instructions, but did not relax the operand requirement, so it seems to be an intentional restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered the same thing. The context-switch use-case is addressed by XSAVE, so yes, I expect most MXCSR accesses are indeed to change FP rounding modes or check / clear FP exception status.

Perhaps the idea is to decouple FP scheduling from integer scheduling, but efficient store-forwarding to make it not a disaster requires schedulers to track things.  And much more common instructions like `ucomiss` (compare into EFLAGS) already need to get FP results to integer.

Seems like a poor design decision to me.  This was made for SSE1, some years after Pentium Pro, so there was time for hindsight on the RISC influences in that design and whether they were worth the hardware simplifications.

I wonder if `st/ldmxcsr` to/from memory was desirable to avoid having to bounce through integer, e.g. if you have two different rounding modes you want to load alternately.  And if they were providing that, they maybe didn't want to *also* provide a different way for the same uop to decode which needs a uop that copies to or from the integer registers and forwarding network.  It wasn't until SSE2 `movd xmm0, r32` vs. `movd xmm0, m32` that we had those different behaviours for XMM regs.  But MMX existed on P2 / P3 before SSE1, requiring the same thing for MMX regs.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess there is no systematic reason. Has there ever been an example of an instruction which was later extended to newly allow register (or memory) operands? Anyway, my question arose from reading the glibc source for emulated FMA (sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/s_fma.c), which uses the inexact flag to yield correct rounding. Absent store forwarding, it probably would be faster latency wise to emulate the inexact flag, like using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2Sum. (I'm in an environment without access to floating point control, so that's what I'll do anyway.)

Comment: @OvinusReal: Yes, 286/287 added `fstsw ax` separate from `fstsw m16`, but that was a separate opcode.  https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/insref.htm#insFSTSW .  `fstsw` is part of the critical path for x87 compare/branch, so it's vastly more important than `ldmxcsr`.  A more recent case is AVX1 `vbroadcastss/sd x/ymm, mem` being extended to support an XMM source in AVX2, removing the restriction on the ModR/M byte for the same opcode.  (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast)

Comment: Even though there are other SSE instructions that can take a GP register operand, they are relatively few.  I wonder if they are treated as a special case that needs extra silicon to implement.  If so then they might have wanted to avoid doing that for instructions like `ld/stmxcsr` that don't really need it.  By contrast, practically all SSE instructions can take a memory operand, so that machinery could be used for free.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Yeah, that's plausible.  Also, storing to the store-buffer brings that mechanism in to handle dependencies on the reload; perhaps a dependency on FP-exception status of all previous FP instructions is harder than a compare between two specific inputs, since OoO exec of FP operations is normally possible despite maybe setting the "sticky" exception-happened bits in MXCSR.